# Firestore display query result in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am not able to manage correctly the sync, async, and promises part related to Firestore query.
I provide you a simplified version of my scenario.
I have different categories of items and I want to display all the category with all items related in a particular way. This is defined by the function Display, that accept as a parameter an array, that contains items belonging to a category.

```
categories=["ct1","ct2"]
....

async function getItems(category){
let items=[]
const snap =  await db.collection("items").where("category","array-contains",category).get()
snap.forEach((doc=>trainers.push(doc.data())))
return items;
}

....

LOOP ON CATEGORIES

Display(getItems(category))
```

Now the problem is the part of handling Promise. getItems return a promise not an array. How can I solve the problem and passing the data retrieved from Firestore to display function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` your `getItems` call.

`async/await` are just syntactic sugar for Promises, so marking a function as `async` will cause it to return a Promise, which you need to `await`:

```js
const items = await getItems('ct1')
// items is now an array
```

Comment: I try it but it is shown this error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: Can you show a more complete example? You might need to use `.then` if you're not in an async context, or change the code that calls this so that it can use `await`